# Alternative Embedded Text Editor

Tags: text-editor, kde4

**System Settings > Default applications > Embedded Text Editor** suggests that you can choose another alternative Embedded Text Editor, but there no other choice but the default *Embedded Advanced Text Editor*.

Where do I find alternative Embedded Text Editors?

The reason I would like to replace the default is that it does not deliver. It is not an editor, but a viewer. I would like to find one that does like the name suggest, namely edit.